# How did this "Plz Help me its urgent" question make it through the filter?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

This is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178552/can-resolve-chat-in-jsf-primeface-plz-help-me-its-urgent

[image: screenshot]

Is the filter malfunctioning? Surely "plz help" and "urgent" are excellent bad-quality indicators!

Comment: Link is 10K only now.

Comment: Yeah, figured that would happen - that's why I screenshotted it.

Comment: I disagree with the whole concept behind this filter.

Comment: At least they lose all rep.

Comment: This question didn't go through the filter. It catapulted itself over the filter. A risky endeavour which is only successful ever so often.

Comment: @Sam you seriously want to see questions like the one above on Stack Overflow? In addition to all the bad/mediocre stuff that makes it through already? This filter is the only reason why Stack Overflow still works.

Comment: @Pekka웃 To be honest, I don't trust the filter.  I think it will hit too many false positives to be worth it.

Comment: This sort of post makes me wonder if it was edited within the 5 minute grace period after a better question made it through the filter.